# Position fixed div with relative to the parent container

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add a `div` in right sidebar which is fixed and relative to the parent container just like this in this [website](https://hostingfacts.com/hosting-reviews/siteground/) see the right sidebar this is exactly what I want for my website

I tried many things but not got any result here is my code

```
<div id="parent_div">
 <div id="fixed_div">
  Some Content here.....
 </div>
</div>


parent_div
{
 float:right;
 width:300px;
 margin-top:50px;
 margin-right:5px;
 position:relative;
 border:1px solid red;
}

fixed_div
{
 position:fixed;
 width:300px;
 background-color:#084B8A;
 padding:10px;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

How can I do this in css which is cross browser and if it is not possible in css how can I do this in jquery or javascript

Comment: You have an example of what you want. The normal thing to do is to figure out how they are doing whatever it is you desire. You can do this by looking in your browser's Dev Tools and looking at the CSS/HTML/JavaScript they are using.

Comment: You could try giving the element `position:sticky; top:0` - otherwise do as on the sample page - update the element CSS onscroll.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of jquery `scrollTop`.Have a look at the below code.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#theFixed").css("top",Math.max(0,250-$(this).scrollTop()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="theFixed" style="position:fixed;top:250px;right:30px;background-color:red">Fixed Div</div>

CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>CONTENT <BR>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use position:sticky;

or else use function

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $(".sidebar").addClass("active");
    } else {
        //remove the background property so it comes transparent again (defined in your css)
       $(".sidebar").removeClass("active");
    }
});
```